# Getting lookup key for datastage job in xmeta database

Tags: lookup, datastage

I'm trying to complete huge task connected with searching in XMETA database, it's almost done but I can't get information about normal lookup's key and query in db connector connected with sparse lookup. I'm thankfull for every hints, I haven't any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The xmeta database is not documented and such details are extremely hard figure out. 
I suggest to base the solution on a Datastage project export (XML preferably or dsx). This might be easier to search and find things you are looking for.